# Using spring saml without other spring frameworks

Tags: spring-mvc, saml, spring-saml

Is it possible to use the Spring Security SAML extension without using other Spring libraries and projects?

I am trying to using Spring SAML libraries in an existing project written in pure Java. I do not intend to use Spring MVC and other libraries. Do I still have to use the securityContext.xml , ContextLoaderListener and DelegatingFilterProxy referenced in web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

Spring SAML security extension relies on the Spring IoC container. You don't need Spring MVC.

Comment: Thank you.  Does any Spring component require Spring IoC?

Comment: Spring is all about 'Inversion of Control' pattern.